# Как перевести "next time, that is" на русский?

Tags: перевод, значения

Как бы вы перевели второе предложение?

It's cute, but make sure you practice before next time. If there's a next time, that is.

Как вариант, я попробовала:

Убедись, что позанимаешься. По крайней мере, до следующего раза.

Насколько он грамотный/правильный? Можете предложить еще какие-то варианты?

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Russian SE! К сожалению, стеки очень плохо заточены под вопросы где нужно предложить список вариантов и, теоретически, каждый из этих вариантов может иметь свои сильные и слабые стороны. Переводы как таковые тоже вне рамок тем, которые мы тут обсуждаем: одно дело спросить о значении непонятного слова или фразы, другое - быть аналогом google translate - при этом ещё и далеко неидеальным аналогом.

Comment: Здравствуйте, вы имеете ввиду все стеки или конкретно этот? Я уже задавала похожие вопросы (с просьбой подкинуть варианты) на английском и корейском stack exchange. Впервые в таким сталкиваюсь.

Comment: можете, пожалуйста, привести примеры ваших вопросов на параллельных стеках - таких вопросов, которые вам кажутся аналогичными? мы стараемся быть консистентными с другими языковыми стеками.

Comment: «Обязательно потренируйся до следующего раза. То есть, если следующий раз вообще будет».That is = то есть.

Comment: shabunc, вот этот:
https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/6314/translating-and-comparing-the-sentences

Comment: спасибо! а на английском? дело в том, что есть тонкая грань между поиском аналогичной фразы на языке N (ну, например, как сказать "душонка" по-английски - это, правда, on-topic на английском стеке) и художественным переводом предложения. 
мы, разумеется, ориентировались на практики уже существующих стеков. Что касается корейского, то они ещё в бете и, возможно, ещё нащупывают что он-топ, что офф-топ

Comment: На английском надо покапаться, давно вопрос задавала. Скажите, если я добавлю в этот вопрос больше контекста и вариантов своего перевода, вы сможете его опубликовать? Или вы вопросы по художественному переводу впринципе не публикуете?

Comment: @GoldenWood если это прямо художественный перевод - то да, но, повторюсь, грань тут тонкая. Во-первых я всего лишь один из модераторов, бывает и так (хотя редко), что я не согласен с другими модераторами или они со мной, иногда пользователи голосуют за переоткрытие. Во-вторых, переформулировка иногда помогает, но в данном случае вряд ли. Вы понимаете, что значит фраза по-русски, вы её правильно перевели, что касается вопросов стилистических - то это бывает и он-топ и офф-топ. В данном случае лично моё мнение что это всё-таки офф-топ.

Comment: @GoldenWood: hi and welcome to Russian.SE! Translation questions are tricky indeed. We are a q&a site about Russian language, and you seem to be a Russian speaker confused about the meaning of an English phrase. Your Russian phrase is good and correct, it just does not mean what the English one means, and explaining the meaning of English phrases is off topic here. Yes, we do lack a stack for translation requests between different languages, like https://www.reddit.com/r/translator/ YellowSky's translation is good. Thanks!

Comment: Там смысл: но к следующему разу подучись. Если он вообще будет, этот следующий. Вот в чем дело.

Comment: V.V. Да, я хотела так перевести, но фраза "вот в чем дело" немного не походит. Она больше про "дело". А там про время (...a next time, that is..) Какие-то еще варианты не знаете? Или сайты, словари какие-нибудь, которые могут помочь? Не могу нигде найти примеры перевода.

Comment: :) Фраза "Вот в чём дело" не является частью перевода. Вам @YellowSky выше дал перевод. Прочитайте внимательно. Ваш перевод в вопросе неверный, потому что вы не понимаете, что значит "that is". Никакого "по крайней мере" там нет.

Comment: @tum_ cпасибо, да, вы правы, я не поняла предложение.

Comment: @YellowSky спасибо за перевод!!